# Scalikejdbc teradata "Connection pool is not yet initialized."

Tags: scala, teradata, scalikejdbc

I'm trying to use ScalikeJdbc with Teradata but can't seem to get it to work. I have a configuration file:

```
application.conf

# JDBC settings
db.default.user="user"
db.default.password="pass"
# Connection Pool settings
db.default.poolInitialSize=10
db.default.poolMaxSize=20
db.default.connectionTimeoutMillis=1000

# Teradata
db.default.driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"
db.default.url="jdbc:teradata://url/database=db"
```

The code looks like this:

```
import scalikejdbc._
import scalikejdbc.config._


object DBObject {
  DBs.setupAll()

  case class Ad(id: Long, siteId: Int)
  object Ad extends SQLSyntaxSupport[Ad] {
    override val tableName = "ad_table"

    def apply(rs: WrappedResultSet) = new Ad(rs.long("id"), rs.int("ad"))
  }

  ConnectionPool.borrow("default")
  val ad = Ad.syntax("ad")
  val ads = DB(ConnectionPool.borrow()) readOnly { implicit session =>
    withSQL {
      select.from(Ad as ad).where.eq(ad.siteId, 3001).limit(10)
    }.map(rs => Ad(rs)).list.apply
  }
}
```

While running this example it throws an exception: `Connection pool is not yet initialized.`
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Tim, I suppose it doesn't depend on specifically Teradata. Just try to initialize default connection pool first. 
Small example for Postgres:

```
object Main extends App {

  def run() = {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
    val poolSettings = new ConnectionPoolSettings(initialSize = 100, maxSize = 100)
    val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
    val user = "postgres"
    val password = "postgres"

    // create singleton(default) connection pool
    ConnectionPool.singleton(url, user, password, poolSettings)

    DB.localTx { implicit session ⇒
      val foos = Foo.findAll()
      println(foos)
    }
  }

  run()
}
```